# React Native Maps - Draggable marker not working on first press

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I have an issue with React Native Maps and draggable markers.

The dragging does not work on the first press. I need to first touch/press the marker then long press to be able to drag it. I would like to be able to long-press it once and be able to drag it.

Can I make the marker draggable on the first long press?

Here is a sample of code I am using:

```
 const Map = ({}) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <MapView
        style={styles.map}
        initialRegion={{
          latitude: 51.58825,
          longitude: -0.1324,
          latitudeDelta: 0.05,
          longitudeDelta: 0.1,
        }}>
        <Marker
          draggable
          coordinate={{
            latitude: 51.58825,
            longitude: -0.1324,
          }}
        />
      </MapView>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  map: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
  },
});
```

Comment: I'm assuming you're experiencing this on iOS with Apple Maps and not Android / Google Maps? Apparently this is intentional - see [this issue](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/issues/1050) and the workaround suggested there in [this comit](https://github.com/freshnewegg/react-native-maps/commit/a0965efe97844317e81aee027bfe519914437be2)